# getting the highest value from an associative array in and if equal, get the highest with the lowest other value

Tags: php, arrays

Let me try and explain this as easy as possible. I have an array which contains the shipping fees of several products.

I have the value of

Item ID
Local Shipping
International Shipping
Additional Local Shipping
Additional International Shipping

To make it easier, I just need to know how to calculate the part of the local shipping. I can afterwards apply the same formula to the international shipping part.

The array may contain 1 or 5 or 100 products, each with their own different (or same) amounts, like this:

```
Array ( 

    [0] => Array ( 
        [item_id] => 788 
        [local_shipping] => 13.00 
        [intl_shipping] => 45.00 
        [addl_local_shipping] => 10.00 
        [addl_intl_shipping] => 20.00 
    )
    [1] => Array ( 
        [item_id] => 234 
        [local_shipping] => 23.00 
        [intl_shipping] => 5.00 
        [addl_local_shipping] => 1.00 
        [addl_intl_shipping] => 2.00 
    )
    [2] => Array ( 
        [item_id] => 543 
        [local_shipping] => 23.00 
        [intl_shipping] => 6.00 
        [addl_local_shipping] => 0.50 
        [addl_intl_shipping] => 5.00 
    )

)
```

So, what I'm trying to get is the array that contains the HIGHEST local_shipping value, which in that case would be both [1] and [2] with "23.00".

If there's only one unique highest value, I need it to return the "local_shipping" and the "addl_local_shipping" like

```
Local Shipping is 23.00 and additional local shipping is 1.00
```

Now, if there's 2 arrays with common highest values, I need it to return the one with the LOWEST "addl_local_shipping" value, which in that case is [2] like:

```
Local Shipping is 23.00 and additional local shipping is 0.50
```

Does that make sense?

I was able to get the highest "local_shipping" value out of the array with this:

```
$max = 0;
foreach( $my_array as $k => $v )
{
$max = max( array( $max, $v['local_shipping'] ) );
}
echo "Local Shipping is " . $max;
```

But I have no idea how to figure out how to print the related "addl_local_shipping" string AND sort out the problem if there are multiple ones with an equal high value.

Comment: "The array may contain 1 or 5 or 100 products" - what's the source of this array?

Comment: It's from a mySQL query. But the structure will always remain the same. The ID will always be numerical as will the cost values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `usort` to sort the array based on local shipping descending and additional ascending, then take the values from the 1st result in the array:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b){
    return $b['local_shipping'] - $a['local_shipping'] ?:
        $a['addl_local_shipping'] - $b['addl_local_shipping'];
});

echo 'local shipping: ' . $array[0]['local_shipping'];
echo 'additional local shipping: ' . $array[0]['addl_local_shipping'];
```

However, as noted in comments, if you are getting this data from an sql query, it makes more sense to let the database do the work for you with an `ORDER BY` clause. The result will be the same - the 1st element in the array will have the data you require

Comment: Was writing down the same idea, so only one additional idea: just query the records with `ORDER BY local_shipping DESC, addl_local_shipping ASC` instead of using usort....

Comment: @VolkerK oh yes, i didnt see the comment about the source of the array - if coming from a sql query then yes that is certainly the best way to do it. Will ammend with a note

Comment: Indeed, I was completely overthinking it. Your answer is the correct one. I used mySQL and it works :)